# Write glossary entries without forcing capitalisation in any context

Tags: glossaries, capitalization

I'm trying to create a glossary entry macro where the text does not enforce any case style.

`\newglossaryentry` seems to force the text to title-case, and using `\MakeLowercase` in my macro forces entries to lower case.

I just want the entries to be the same case as what's written. Is there a way to "revert" or cancel the command that made them title case?

Edit: More specifically, I use a macro to define glossary entries like so:

```
% Glossary entry macro.
\newcommand{\GlsDef}[2]
{
  \newglossaryentry{#1}
  {
    name={\capitalisewords{#1}}, % As it appears in the glossaries page.
    first={\textbf{#1}},         % First time appearance in text.
    text={#1},                   % Standard appearance in text.
    description={#2}             % Description in glossaries page.
  }
}
```

Which I then use like:

```
\GlsDef{foo}{A common placeholder variable name for demo program code.
See also: \Gls{bar}.}
```

The problem is that with this definition, if I try to refer to foo in the beginning of a sentence, like so: `\Gls{foo} is capitalized!` it doesn't work. If I remove the `first={\textbf{#1}},` line, however, the foo will become capitalized as expected.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: That's not the default behaviour of `\newglossaryentry`. As @ChristianHupfer has already commented, we need a MWE to see what's switching it on.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot: Since you're the author of `glossaries`, I leave it to you (given there will be a MWE)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I don't mind if anyone else wants to answer :-) but I'll answer if no one else does (provided a MWE that illustrates the problem is added).

Comment: Try downloading [this example file](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/samples/minimalgls.tex) and [build it up](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/html/buildingup.html) until you see the problem.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot: I answered some `glossaries` questions already here, but you know definitely best about your packages ;-)

Comment: Don't put `\textbf{}` in `first` and I bet it will work fine. Then alter the format of first-time entries globally as required.

Comment: Actually, it works fine for me as it is anyway. But it would still be better not to include explicit mark-up in `first`.

Comment: @cfr it seems to me that `first` is literally made for explicit mark-up.

Comment: If you want the first occurrence of each term to be formatted differently from other occurrences ***and*** differently from the first occurrence of other terms, yes. If you want the first occurrences of all terms to be formatted consistently, though, it is bad to do it this way: if you decide you want them to be in small-caps, say, rather than bold, you'll need to change `first` for every single glossary entry rather than changing one line of code.

Comment: @cfr I've only changed one line of code. See above.

Comment: In your example, yes. But if you have 2 entries, you will change 2 lines of code and if you have 20 entries, 20 lines of code. That makes this solution inflexible and difficult to adapt and maintain.

Comment: @cfr I think you should look again. My solution is a macro.

Comment: You are right. I apologise for missing that. However, this still strikes me as a less than ideal way of doing it. It seems to me that the formatting of the entries in various contexts ought to be configured separately from the specification of the content of those entries. That seems more consonant with LaTeX's approach, even if the inflexibility of mixing format with content in this case is mitigated by the use of a macro.

Comment: Agree that it isn't ideal, but in a programming/data format context, I don't think that changing a global setting is very elegant either. Alas, I think this problem is resolved though. Thanks for taking an interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works fine for me:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[nopostdot]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newcommand{\GlsDef}[2]
{%
  \newglossaryentry{#1}%
  {
    name={\capitalisewords{#1}}, % As it appears in the glossaries page.
    first={\textbf{#1}},         % First time appearance in text.
    text={#1},                   % Standard appearance in text.
    description={#2}             % Description in glossaries page.
  }
}

\GlsDef{foo}{A common placeholder variable name for demo program
code.  See also: \Gls{bar}.}

\GlsDef{bar}{Something else.}

\begin{document}

First use upper: \Gls{foo} and \Gls{bar}.

Next use upper: \Gls{foo} and \Gls{bar}.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: image of result]

**A note on the first letter case-changing commands.**

Commands like `\Gls` internally use `\makefirstuc` provided by the `mfirstuc` package. This works as follows:

1. If the argument if `\makefirstuc` doesn't start with a command (e.g. just `\makefirstuc{foo}`) the first thing in the argument is converted to upper case (e.g. it just does `\MakeUppercase foo`).
2. If the argument of `\makefirstuc` starts with a command followed by a group (like `\textbf{foo}`) it will convert the first thing in the group to upper case. (For example, `\textbf{\MakeUppercase foo}`).
3. If the argument starts with a command that isn't followed by a group (like `\oe foo`) it assumes the command produces a character and applies the upper casing to that command. (For example, `\MakeUppercase \oe foo`.)

If we add `\showglofirst{foo}` to the MWE (after `foo` has been defined), the following shows up in the transcript:

```
> \glo@foo@first=macro:
->\protect \textbf  {foo}.
<recently read> \glo@foo@first
```

This means that `first={\textbf{foo}}` has actually been converted to `first={\protect\textbf{foo}}` because expansion is on for the `first` key. This means the `\Gls{foo}` is now trying to do `\makefirstuc{\protect\textbf{foo}}`. This falls under item 3 above, so it's equivalent to `\MakeUppercase\protect\textbf{foo}` so the upper casing isn't applied to `foo`.

Version 2.01 of `mfirstuc` added an extra check. If the argument of `\makefirstuc` starts with `\protect` discard the `\protect` and try again. So with v2.01, the above MWE works fine. For versions below 2.01, the simplest fix is to switch off the expansion. This can be done explicitly for just the `first` field using:

```
\glssetnoexpandfield{first}
```

Adding `\showglofirst{foo}` now shows the following in the transcript:

```
> \glo@foo@first=macro:
->\textbf {foo}.
<recently read> \glo@foo@first
```

This means that `\Gls{foo}` now does `\makefirstuc{\textbf{foo}}`, which works fine for older versions of `mfirstuc`.

Comment: Excuse my lack of response to this topic - I expected to receive an email but seems I was wrong. I don't have an MWE but I have been playing more with this issue and I think I see what happens. I have a macro (which I will edit into my original question) which uses the `first` property of `newglossaryentry`. This seems to be the part that breaks it. Without `first`, I can get `Gls` and `GlS` and `GLS` to behave properly.

Comment: @Cokemonkey11 In what way does it break? (An error message or incorrect formatting?) It may be that you're using an old version of `glossaries` or `mfirstuc`.

Comment: The formatting is incorrect - `\Gls` produces a bold but *not* Capitalized entry. I am using miktex which is synchronised to package db. glossaries packaged on 2015-12-01, glossaries-english packaged on 2015-05-30, and mfirstuc packaged on 2015-09-11.

Comment: @Cokemonkey11 I've checked and it's the `mfirstuc` version that's the problem. I've modified my answer.

Comment: your solution in the modified answer works perfectly. I wonder if it's worth getting MiKTeX to include the latest mfirstuc version, so people can avoid this `\glsetnoexpandfield{first}` hack in future.

Comment: @Cokemonkey11 I don't know how quickly MiKTeX incorporates updates (I don't use it), but I expect it will get there soon. It's a fairly recent release. (There's actually a newer `mfirstuc` version 2.02, but the pertinent change for this question is addressed in 2.01.)